# Not able to resolve HttpResponseException in .Net 5 Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, webapi

I am creating an Web Api using .Net Core 5.  I want to implement error handling and return the response with the error.  I found a article from Microsoft which suggested the following code.  When I am implementing that code "HttpResponseException" is not found and I get a suggestion to install the nuget package for Microsoft.Aspnet.WebApi.Core.  Once install it conflicting with the existing nuget package. I got this message "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.8 was restored using .netFramework, Version=4.6.1..."   As I said,  I am trying to handling error as per best practices and my finding was to use Microsoft documentation in which it mentioned to use HttpResponseException (applicable scenario). If HttpResponseException is obsolete for .Net 5 what other option we have? Basically in the response when error occured, I want to send the customize ReasonPhrase.

[image]

```
public Product GetProduct(int id)
{
Product item = repository.Get(id);
if (item == null)
{
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(string.Format("No product with ID = {0}", id)),
        ReasonPhrase = "Product ID Not Found"
    };
    throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
}
return item;
```

}